# How do I replace gedit settings or preferably the code snippets?

Tags: gedit

So as many other users I have several computers and it is tedious to write the `code snippets` twice and change settings twice. So my question is this:
Is there an easy way to replace the settings of `gedit`? In particular I'm looking for a way to add the extra code snippets from one of the computers to the other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI way to doing this is -

1. Going Menu to **Tools** -> **Manage Snippets**
2. Then select all snippets using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
3. Click on the export icon.

It will ask where you want to export all snippets. After selecting the directory, all snippets will be exported into a compressed file `Snippets archive.tar.gz` in that directory. You can then import this archive using same GUI options **Import Snippets** button.

[image: export and import button]

All these snippets are actually stored at `~/.config/gedit/snippets` directory. If you want you can also use command line tools to copy the contents of that directory to a new computer. The snippets should be restored.